# How does a double tile in muggins count?

Tags: scoring, dominoes

In a game of muggins, do you count a  double 5 as 10 or just 5? Since some people have been saying that a double 5 you only count one side. From my knowledge you count both sides of the domino; for example double 5 = 10, double 3 = 6.

Comment: "Count" for what purposes? And also what specific game are you playing? "Dominoes" by itself is not a game, it's like saying "cards". There are lots of different games you can play with a set of Dominoes.

Comment: Need more information on which game you are playing with your Dominoes.

Comment: For example muggins and the game is blocked and no one can play anymore. The player with the least amount of pipes on their cards wins. Now do you count a card like double 5 as 10. Some people say that it only counts as 5

Comment: Feel like the title can be improved but without more information not sure how.  But I came in not knowing what was asked by the title and I am leaving not knowing what is asked by the title :P

Answer (score 1):

All pips count, so a double five, having ten pips, counts for 10.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muggins):

> The player who goes out wins additional points based on the value of dominoes still in other players' hands, which is scored by counting all the pips on those dominoes.